# Gradle use different tasks / arguments for each build type

Tags: android, gradle

I'm in the early stages of migrating an android project to gradle, using the experimental plugin 0.4.0

As part of the build process I have a number of scripts that should run prior to compiling my code / building the apk. The arguments or tasks themselves will be different for a debug or release build.

I'm struggling to find a straight forward way to achieve this.

I've stripped everything back to a simple hello world project while I figure this out.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        debug {
            //
        }
        release {
            //runProguard, sign etc.
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("free")
        {
            applicationId = "com.example.app.free"
            versionName = "1.0-free"
        }
        create("full")
        {
            applicationId = "com.example.app.full"
            versionName = "1.0-full"
        }
    }
}

repositories { 
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
}

task runScript(type: Exec) {
    executable "sh"
    args "-c", "echo SomeScriptHere"
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn runScript
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.5'
}
```

Ideally I want to differentiate by buildType ( not productFlavor ) as the tasks required as based on the type of build not the variety of app produced.

Is it possible to specify that a task should only run on a release or debug build?

Alternatively is it possible to define different arguments to be used for my runScript task based on being a release or debug build?

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, I'm pretty new to using gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using onlyIf() would be one option [gradle docs here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) but having to define properties seemed awkward especially as a project gets larger and more complicated.

ZXStudio has a good blog post / example [here](http://zxstudio.org/blog/2015/11/25/running-an-external-task-with-build-variant-dependent-parameters-in-gradle/) where instead of using properties or rules will iterate over the existing tasks and create a new task based on the buildType / flavor.

So for my original question the answer mean removing the runScript task above and replacing tasks.withType(JavaCompile) as follows;

Could also be extended to match build flavors and create tasks appropriately.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    def newTaskName = "runScript_" + name;
    def isDebug = false;

    if( name.contains("Debug") )
    {
        isDebug = true;
    }

    //Create a new task
    tasks.create( newTaskName, Exec ) {
        if( isDebug )
        {
            executable "sh"
            args "-c", "echo this is a DEBUG task"
        }
        else 
        {
            executable "sh"
            args "-c", "echo this is a RELEASE task"
        }
    }

    dependsOn newTaskName
}
```